# Suggest a method for deleteing small data from huge table in oracle

Tags: indexing, oracle10g, sql-delete

I have a table with aound 300 million rows. I need to delete approx 3 million from it. I don't have any index on this table. Data will be deleted based on a specific date column. Like

```
delete from table where column_name = '1-dec-2010'
```

What would be the best solution to perform this?

1. Index the column and perform delete.
2. Keep table as it is i.e. delete without using index

Using index will use index scan + overhead of updating index after delete. Without index will use full table scan. So is there any threshold which says that after X million rows index is preferred over full table scan?

Comment: Is this a one-off, or a regular job?

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options (in order of efficiency):

1. Partitioning. Extra-cost option for Enterprise Edition. If the data is partitioned by day, then removing the data of the given day is as simple as dropping the partition of the day. Fast, efficient, nice, but expensive (unless customer can get good discounts).
2. Create a new table and copy the data you want to keep into the new table (use direct path insert). Drop old table; rename new table (or use dynamically managed synonyms). Index might be useful in this case, although more likely that Oracle will ignore this as the selectivity is not good (only around 1% of the data is to be accessed; the optimizer might think it's not worth to deal with an index).
   See [Tom Kyte's comments](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689) on this option.
3. Use index. This will definitely accelerate finding the records that need to be deleted, but the deletion will be still painfully slow (redo and all).

Comment: Hey Barany, thanks for the answer. As this is an existing table we are not changing the structure by partitioning it. As per 2nd option, we tried it on 100M table but surpricingly it was slower than simple delete using indexes. I have even tested deleteing 3M out of 180M records and indexed delete was faster than non indexed delete. but i am not sure if same will happen as data goes beyond 300M.

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you deleting a fixed 1% of your data?  If so, and partitioning is not to be considered, do the following:

1. Create your index on the date column.
2. Make sure that optimizer statistics are gathered for that index and for the table.

Run a query like the following:

```
select di.table_name, di.index_name, di.leaf_blocks, 
       di.clustering_factor, dt.blocks
  from all_indexes di
       left join all_tables dt
         on di.table_owner = dt.owner
        and di.table_name = dt.table_name
 where di.index_name = 'my_new_index'
```

- `LEAF_BLOCKS` gives you a rough size of the "data blocks" of the
  index.
- `CLUSTERING_FACTOR` tells you how many table I/Os would be
  required to read the entire table by that index.
- `BLOCKS` gives you
  the size of the table in blocks.

If `CLUSTERING_FACTOR` is very close to the size of `BLOCKS`, then the table is more-or-less stored in the order the index is in.

So if you're deleting 1% of the table, see which is smaller:

`BLOCKS`, or `((LEAF_BLOCKS + CLUSTERING_FACTOR) / 100)`

If BLOCKS is significantly larger - probably on the order of 10x larger - than the calculated expression, then the index will probably speed up the delete.